# How I can put limits on the rotation of the camera on the Y axis? Help me §

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, camera

I can't put a limit on the rotation on the Y axis and also I would have my player look in the direction he is moving , I have already tried to put **Mathf.calmp** for the **Touchfiled.Touchdist.y** (camera Y axis) but it doesn't work I don't know where the problem comes from but I would like to solve it so please help me.
here is my code :

```
    public FloatingJoystick joystick;
    public TouchField touchField;
    public GameObject FocusPoint;

    [HideInInspector] public CharacterController characterController;
    [HideInInspector] public Vector3 motionVector , gravityVector, RelativeVector;

    [Header("Player Settings")]
    [Range(0,6)] public float PlayerSpeed = 2.5f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float Sensivility = 50;
    [Range(0, 0.5f)] public float groundClearance;

    private float gravityForce = -9.18f;
    private float gravityPower = -9.8f;
    private float JumpValue = 9.8f;
    private float TurnDiraction;

    private void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Movment();
        CameraController();

        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            print("Grounded");
        }

    }

    public void CameraController()
    {
        RelativeVector = transform.InverseTransformPoint(FocusPoint.transform.position);
        RelativeVector /= RelativeVector.magnitude;
        TurnDiraction = (RelativeVector.x / RelativeVector.magnitude);
        FocusPoint.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(FocusPoint.transform.eulerAngles.x + touchField.TouchDist.y, FocusPoint.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0) ;
        FocusPoint.transform.parent.Rotate(transform.up * touchField.TouchDist.x * Sensivility * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    public void Movment()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded && gravityVector.y < 0)
        {
            gravityVector.y = -2;
        }

        gravityVector.y += gravityPower * Time.deltaTime;
        characterController.Move(gravityVector * Time.deltaTime);

        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            motionVector = transform.right * joystick.Horizontal + transform.forward * joystick.Vertical;
            characterController.Move(motionVector * PlayerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            if(joystick.Vertical > 0)
            {
                transform.Rotate(transform.up * TurnDiraction * 800 * Time.deltaTime);
                FocusPoint.transform.parent.Rotate(transform.up * -TurnDiraction * 800 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You rotate in 2 steps, and in the second and in the second one you do:

`FocusPoint.transform.parent.Rotate(transform.up * touchField.TouchDist.x * Sensivility * Time.deltaTime);`

If you rotate the parent respect the y axis all the children turn along with the rotation given to the parent in the hierarchy.
So it does not matter that you clamp the y rotation in the previous step

`FocusPoint.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(FocusPoint.transform.eulerAngles.x + touchField.TouchDist.y, FocusPoint.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);`

if the gameobject is going to be rotated respect y axis after.

Try rotating at once according to your limits, or take into account those limits for all the rotation steps.

On the other hand, gravity is neither a power, nor a force, but an acceleration :)